# Blurry text with css scaled iframe in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe, scale, blur

This question, there is a point that is different from the "css scale chrome" other questions.
iframe is moved to a specific location, text will be displayed correctly.
And, when moved to a position where there is a problem again, the text will be blur.

Move will be executed position of jquery.

Why iframe is moved, text will be displayed correctly?

screen shots.
http://ggamagidev.blogspot.com/2013/12/blurry-text-with-css-scaled-iframe-in.html

It is applied to the iframe, but they failed.

```
// transform: "translateZ(0)",
// "-webkit-transform": "translateZ(0)",
// "-webkit-text-stroke": "0.35px",
// "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
// "-webkit-transform-style": "preserve-3d",
// "transform-style": "flat",
// "-webkit-transform-style": "flat",
// "font-smooth":"never",
// "-webkit-perspective":1000,
// "backface-visibility": "hidden",
// "-webkit-backface-visibility":"hidden",
```

Comment: some transforms cause font hinting to be turned off

Comment: It has nothing to do with this bug. Text of the two screen shots are hinted both.

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. I was remembering the details of the problem wrong. I believe this has already been asked, but I can't find it. I seem to remember that in chrome there is a workaround with `backface-visibility: hidden` that fixes the issue. `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: '-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;' failed. All text is blurred in the iframe.

Comment: Have you solved this blur issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try if font blurred in chrome.

```
body {-webkit-text-stroke: 0px!important;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;}
```