# Why Chrome render Iframe content blurry?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I use *iframes* in my web project and *Chrome* render the iframes content blurry, can't understand why and how can fix it. 
I try, 
giving `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) perspective(1px) scale(1.01);` to iframe, 
set to *body* `-webkit-text-stroke: 0px;` `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`  
and wrap my iframe in div which have a `position: relative;`

Example here: [image: Blurry iframe content on Chrome]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blurry text with css scaled iframe in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706279/blurry-text-with-css-scaled-iframe-in-chrome)

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth Where the true answer? all answers not confirmed by author???

Comment: Have you tried their solutions?